# Java: get pacific timezone without DST

Tags: java, timezone

I need to use Pacific timezone in my code that **doesn't** incorporate DST. I know that `America/Los_Angeles` takes DST into account. When I try to use `PST`, the time API throws this exception:

```
java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: PST
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It appears to me to be a peculiar requirement, so I am wondering if it could be some [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Would you explain why you need that? I believe that this will help us help you to find the best option (there are some).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yup, it is an XY problem. I don't really want to explain X here because X is something stupid deep in our system and no one has time to fix that. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: In that case it sounds like [Jon Skeet’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55021086/5772882) is the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"PST" isn't a time zone ID.

It sounds like you don't really want to use the Pacific time zone so much as a constant UTC offset of -8 hours. You can do that with:

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8);
```

Answer (score 3):

Options include:

- Use a `ZoneOffset` as already explained in Jon Skeet’s answer. Since `ZoneOffset` is a subclass of `ZoneId`, you can use it everywhere a `ZoneId` is required.
- Use `ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pitcairn")`. This time zone is at offset -08:00 all year. Pitcairn Standard Time is abbreviated PST too.
- For the sake of completeness `ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+8")` gives you a zone ID that is not a `ZoneOffset` but is equivalent to the `ZoneOffset` (`+8` is no typo, the sign is intentionally inverted).

**Link:** [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)